# Will a background check disclose the employment relationship?

Tags: human-resources

Can you help me understand background checks  a bit more? Will a company disclose whether my employment relationship was a regular full-time or 1099 contract? Thank you!

Comment: Since they would call the company to confirm the dates of employment and the HR office would state that you were never an employee, yes I think it would be found most of the time. Why would you want to hide that you were were working as a 1099 contractor though?

Comment: An employment background check normally involves verifying employment, verifying education degrees, criminal checks, and basic credit checks. I'm with @HLGEM as I'm unsure why you would hide or not fully disclose the nature of your employment with some company.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not always – I had one position where I worked full-time as a 1099 and still got vacation time. They would list me as a full-time employee. I also wouldn't be surprised if my first company didn't list "temp" employees who had been there for 6+ months. That said, there is also no guarantee or expectation that they won't say "1099" in both cases.

Something which was taught to me repeatedly in high school and college – you never lie on a résumé, people will find out. I don't know that you will necessarily fall into that position, but if you are concerned about a background check, it is better to omit the job than add risk of being caught in a lie.

Comment: Glad you learned about not lying in high school and college, because if you learned that in the workplace, it means you probably will also lose a job with it.

Comment: @Nelson It's from a history as a performer. I heard multiple stories – from numerous teachers – of people who blatantly lied to get an audition only to find someone from the original cast/production was adjudicating.